# Getting facebook page followers' count with Graph Api and Javascript SDK

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I have django app and I need to show the number of followers of its facebook page.
In my base.html I have hardcoded the number of FB followers, but this is not a feasible longterm solution.

I've been experimenting with inline javascript, and this is the state of my code:

```js
<script>
   window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
     appId      : 'NumOfMyId',
     xfbml      : true,
     version    : 'v2.4'
    });
    FB.api(
     '/MyWebSite',
     'GET',
     {"fields":"likes"},
     function(response) {
      console.log(response);
      //here should go something so that the number of people liking the page gets appended to an html element by id;  
     });
   };

   (function(d, s, id){
    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
    js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
    js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
   }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
   </script>
```

I need the facebook api to give me the number of followers, which is not a problem in the graph api explorer, but I have no clue how to accomplish it in my  tag.

*Any* example/advice or redirecting to similar solved questions/issues/github project would be super appreciated!

~good vibes to y'all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using jQuery on your page, you can do something like this:

```
<p>The total number of likes in my page is <span id="number-of-likes"></span>.</p>


function(response) {
    console.log(response);
    $('#number-of-liles').html(response.NUMBER_OF_LIKES_FIELD);
});
```

Where `response.NUMBER_OF_LIKES_FIELD` is the correct field name that has the number of likes.